# Strange Lines in terminal

Tags: command-line

thoose pictures for the problem I face, I don't know how to it happened but it just happened.. So, I want to know how it happened and how to solve it ?

[image: img1]

[image: img2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the result of You executing some command, which produces logging/debugging output (maybe because of a parameter you specified, who knows?). The program is responsible for its output, some of which may be erroneous or binary. How is this a problem? To make ALL (mostly) of the error messages go away, append `2>/dev/null` to your command.

Comment: Thx for reply,, but sometimes I need to see the error of commands ,to solve it .. So Can't you tell which command(s) that caused this error ?

Comment: Something else, this output is continuously appear, whatever I'm in terminal or nano or even a new terminal ...   So at least how I stop it ?

Comment: Some process you put into the background (by suffixing with `&`) is doing it. Try typing `jobs`. Does your `~/.bashrc` contain a `&`?

Comment: Or, look at all your processes: `ps -fu$USER`